# How can I add mysql abilities to tagmate?

Tags: php, mysql

I was implementing [tagmate](https://github.com/pinterest/tagmate) to a blog and I was wondering how can I add mysql sources if am using php as a back-end. I only want the source to be related to what the user is typing.

Example:

- I type in: `@nick` it's not that simple
- While I type `@nick`, an ajax request is made to a php file that queries a mysql database table and retrieves all the results relevant to what I type.
- This is then brought back in maybe json (I don't know about thispart)
- My tagmate web app gets this info outputs it as the dropdown suggestion list.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: sounds like a really bad idea... are you making a request for each @ sign ? (that can make things really slow) it should be sent as json... and pretty much anything can be accomplished but this question is not only way too broad its also off topic

Comment: What's tagmate? Are you talking about this? https://github.com/pinterest/tagmate

Comment: @JohnRuddell Do you have a better idea? If the site has millions of users you can't exactly preload the data. I would make it fire off an ajax request with each @ if it's followed by 2 or more letters and perhaps preceded by a space.

Comment: Yes thats what I'm talking.

Comment: @Mark well theres a lot that would go into this question.... the question itself needs to be much more specific and show attempts... but what I would do is a timeout function on the input and compare by keypress.. after 1 second if the values are the same that means they stopped typing and it should do the request... but not just when someone types an @ sign... someone could do @@@@ and it could cause some serious issues

Comment: good idea.. @JohnRuddell but i still don't know what my back end should output and what to put as my sources. if i want to  load  mysql content..

Comment: @NicholasMckenzie Stack Overflow is for helping someone fix broken code / attempts.. the problem with your question is there is way too much to answer here... javascript front end to handle input / ajax request... php side handling for user input... sql queries that are parameterized... organizing and pulling out the results... pushing back to javascript through json and then finally displaying on the page... thats a good 7 questions all in one.. and you dont have any attempts either.. also what is your database structure like? theres too much here for one question it needs to be minimized

Comment: @JohnRuddell All I want to know is how my php out would look. you said json, ok. But in the my page a javscript parameter labeled sources has this : {label: "George Washington", value: "george"}, {label: "Abraham Lincoln",value: "abe"}, {label: "Andrew Jackson", value: "andy"}....but what i want is sources to be requested from a php file....
My database is a mysql database...the table is called users and it has only basic user info..

Comment: @NicholasMckenzie but how can I even know that if you don't have any sql structure or anything? fyi i haven't even downvoted... but json is one of the best / easiest languages to send data back and forth so you should use that from php to javascript... I don't know what you would be selecting or how it would even look like coming from a database that I haven't seen

Comment: Ok but thanks for your help so far. I guess I'll have to use what I have.

Comment: @NicholasMckenzie if you post a question with a mysql table structure and a desired outcome for a select I can help you with that... also if you post a question about connecting between javascript and php I can help with that... but with the scope of this question you might as well hire someone to do it if you know what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on that tagmate library is crap. It says the `sources` option will accept a function, but it doesn't tell you what args it receives. If you [dig into the source](https://github.com/pinterest/tagmate/blob/844b1a39aba713bfb504056d8e1101889e24d4fd/jquery.tagmate.js#L341) it looks like it takes a term as the first arg and a function you should call as the 2nd. So you'll want to fire off your ajax request in there and then call `done(results)` when it returns.

[Consult jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to figure out how to perform your ajax request. You'll want to pass along the supplied term to your PHP backend so that you can perform your SQL query.

Something like this:

```
$("#myTextarea").tagmate({
    sources: function(data, done) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/users.php', // will receive $_GET['term']
            data: data
        }).done(function(result) {
            done(result); // should return JSON data in the format [{label:'Mr. Foo',value:'foo'}]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect exactly what i was search for! Thank you @Mark